# move_uploaded_file not moving file to folder

Tags: php, file, upload

I have a form from which I can upload some files. The file array shows up correct when I `print` it but there is no file in the destination folder. What am I missing?

This is my code:

```
// Fileupload
if (!is_dir('../incidentbijlagen/'.$inc['incident']['companyname'].'')) {
    mkdir('../incidentbijlagen/'.$inc['incident']['companyname'].'', 0777, true);
}

$uploads_dir = '../incidentbijlagen/'.$inc['incident']['companyname'].'/';

foreach($bijlage['incident'] as $key => $file){
  $tmp_name = $file['incident']['tmp_name']['bijlage'][$key];
  $name = basename($file['incident']['name']['bijlage'][$key]);
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

There are no errors in my error_log so I am not sure why the file is not moved. This is what my array looks like when I `print` it:

```
Array
(
    [incident] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [bijlage] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => fblogosnm.jpg
                        )

                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [bijlage] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => image/jpeg
                        )

                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [bijlage] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => /tmp/phpnh5aHW
                        )

                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [bijlage] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                        )

                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [bijlage] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20573
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the loop and just try using 0 like this:

```
  $tmp_name = $file['incident']['tmp_name']['bijlage'][0];
  $name = basename($file['incident']['name']['bijlage'][0]);
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
```

UPDATE

OK for multiple, try this:

```
foreach($bijlage['incident']['name']['bijlage'] as $key => $file) {
  $tmp_name = $file['incident']['tmp_name']['bijlage'][$key];
  move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$file");
}
```

Comment: But I want to be able to upload multiple files

Comment: i updated my answer, have you tried it? how did you get on?

Comment: I tried your updated answer but the file still doesn't end up in that folder. It is weird that I am nog getting any errors.

Comment: Try also using `realpath()` on your relative path with the `../`, like Frank suggested in his answer. Could be it isn't finding that folder as well as the array access issue. Realpath will return the absolute path, or false. Var dump it and you'lll see.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace:
`$uploads_dir = '../incidentbijlagen/'.$inc['incident']['companyname'].'/';`

with:
`$uploads_dir = realpath('../incidentbijlagen/'.$inc['incident']['companyname'].'/');`

This returns the full path (e.g.: /var/www/yourwebsite/incidentbijlagen/ etc)

Comment: the problem is he isn't getting the name or temp name, but your suggestion is also good practice

Comment: The file is still not in the folder with above code, I also combined it with delboys answer but no results.

Comment: Did you try to output `$tmp_name` and `"$uploads_dir/$name"`? Then use the output to check if these directories exist on your disk?